# Show that the given map F is a contraction map & find a solution of F, if any.

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, fixed-point-theorems, integral-equations

Given a space of all real-valued continuous function $C[0,1]$ with $sup$ norm, define $$F:C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]\text{  by  } F(x)(t)=x(0)+\lambda\int_{0}^{t}x(s)ds$$ $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ with $|\lambda|<1$ and $t\in [0,1]$.

I cannot understand whether $x(0)$ will be treated as a constant or it will change during the proof.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to prove that $\|F(x) - F(y)\| \leq \|x-y\|$ for any $x, y\in C[0,1]$. So, *fixed* $x$ and $y$, $x(0)$ and $y(0)$ should be constants. $\qquad$

Comment: Yes, I have tried the same thing but then I arrived at, $sup|F(x)-F(y)|\leq sup|x(0)-y(0)|+|\lambda|sup|x(s)-y(s)|$

Comment: is it $x(0)$ or (some a priori fixed) $x_0$ ? $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion $x(0)$ has to be a given constant. Imagine you have found a fix point $x$ of $F$, i.e. $F(x)=x$. Then for every $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ the function $\alpha\cdot x$ satisfies $F(\alpha x)=\alpha x$. This would contradict the uniqueness part of the contraction mapping principle.

EDIT:
Let's sketch a proof: Let $y,z\in C^0([0,1])$, then
$$|F(z)(t)-F(y)(t)|=|x(0)-x(0) + \lambda \int_0^tz(s)-y(s)ds|\leq\lambda\int_0^t|z(s)-y(s)|ds.$$
Hence
$$\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|F(z)(t)-F(y)(t)|\leq \lambda \sup_{t\in[0,1]}|z(t)-y(t)|.$$
Since $0<\lambda<1$ this gives you a contraction. This yields a $y\in C^0([0,1])$ such that
$$y(t)=F(y)(t)=x(0)+\lambda\int_0^ty(s)\, ds.$$
If you like to know how $y$ looks like, you either derive the whole equation by $t$ and obtain an ordinary differential equation or you can try a fix-point iteration, i.e. $z_n:=F(z_{n-1})$, $z_0=0$. The result will be something along the lines of an exponential function.

Comment: can you please elaborate the procedure to show that this map is a contraction?

Comment: @ Sujit Bhattacharyya Done in an edit

Comment: Where you wrote "$x(0)-x(0)$" I think it should be "$z(0) - y(0)$". Am I wrong?

Comment: @rldias No, it is intended. The formulation of the exercise is in my opinion a bit flawed. It should have been something like $x_0$ instead of $x(0)$ because it has to be a fixed constant independ of the function $y$, wich is inserted in $F$, i.e. $F(y)$. Otherwise as you already pointed out in your answer, you cannot expect uniqueness, therefore $F$ cannot be contraction.

Answer (score 1):

*This is just a discussion, not an answer.*

Notice that $(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$ is a Banach space.
Besides, the given map $F$ is linear (thus $F(0) = 0$ and therefore $0\in C[0,1]$ is already a fixed point for $F$).

If $F$ were a contraction it would have a unique fixed point, by Banach fixed point theorem.

However, if there exists a $\bar{x}\in C[0,1]$ such that $\bar{x}\neq 0$ and $F(\bar{x}) = \bar{x}$, then $F(\alpha\bar{x}) = \alpha F(\bar{x}) = \alpha\bar{x}$ for every $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ ($\alpha\bar{x}$ would be a fixed point for $F$, for all $\alpha\in\mathbb R$), which means that $F$ would've infinitely many fixed points.

Therefore, we have two possibilities:

(a) $F$ is not a contraction map; or

(b) $0$ is the only fixed point for $F$.

Comment: You have to be careful here. $\bar{x}$ might be zero. This will exactly happen, if $x(0)=0$.

Comment: @humanStampedist you're absolutely right. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

$|F(x)(t)-f(y)(t)| = |\lambda\int_{0}^{t}(x(s)-y(s))ds| \le | \lambda| \int_{0}^{t}|x(s)-y(s)|ds \le | \lambda| \int_{0}^{1}|x(s)-y(s)|ds \le | \lambda| \int_{0}^{1}||x-y||ds =|\lambda| \cdot ||x-y||$

for all $t \in [0,1]$.

Hence $||F(x)-F(y)|| \le |\lambda| \cdot ||x-y||$ .

Comment: What about $x(0) - y(0)$? Does it change something?

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition

$$F:C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]\text{  by  } F(x)(t)=x(0)+\lambda\int_{0}^{t}x(s)ds$$

$$ F(x)(0) = x(0)+\lambda\int_{0}^{0}x(s)ds=
x(0)$$
Thus, $x(0)$  stays constant.